# Is there a "quickload" function in Eschalon: Book I?

Tags: eschalon-book-i

*Eschalon: Book I* has a "quicksave" function (bound to F2), but is there a "quickload"?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly no, but if you're playing on Windows you can use [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com). Here's an **example** script that binds Control+L to "quickload", assuming you're playing fullscreen 800x600:

```
#NoEnv
^l::
Send {Esc}
MouseMove, 500, 370
Sleep, 200
Click
MouseMove, 500, 250
Sleep, 200
Click
```